# Problem with biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I'm having problems with referencing in Sharelatex.
This is what I try to run but doesn't work. 
Any idea?? Thx.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\graphicspath{ {images/}}

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\setlength{\parskip}{8mm}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\bibliography{ref} %%% from ref.bib file



\title{{ Hello World}\\

\author{User}

\date{January 2016}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\input{chapters/Introduction}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! What goes wrong? Which error messages do you receive?  For `biblatex` you should really use `\addbibreseource` rather than `\bibilography`.

Comment: `\title{{ Hello World}` misses a closing brace.

Comment: If you don't cite anything (either with `\cite` or `\nocite`) in `chapters/Introduction.tex` you are not going to see a bibliography here. But the real issue here is `title{{ Hello World}` as clemens noted.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I figured out what was wrong. I'm writing a thesis and working with different files (introduction/background...) that are organized in folders. The problem was that the main document was in a different folder than the rest of the files, so sharelatex couldnt compile properly.

Comment: Do you want to write an answer then? Or do we close the question as "off topic" (it is not really, we just don't have "too localised" any more)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was about a problem with the ShareLaTeX service which has since been resolved by their support and the OP. The issue is not reproducible from the MWE.